# My app's system alert showing wrongly on top off the 'phone' app

Tags: ios, iphone

My app asks permission for push notification through system alert. At that time, phone call comes. Now that system alert is showing above the phone app

[image]

Comment: Please post image or code, So people can get idea.

Comment: I think this is standard iOS behaviour - notification don't disappear when a call comes in, otherwise you might miss it.

Comment: @MayurKarmur pls find the image

Comment: @MTCoster tell right.

Comment: All of this is beyond your control, it's handled by iOS internally. File a bug or enhancement request if you want to see it changed.

Answer (score 0):

This action is taking control by system. So you can't do anything but file a bug to Apple or let user choose the option. Anyway phone call does work, right?